# Is the REST catalog the same as a nessie catalog in iceberg

Tags: rest, apache-iceberg, nessie

I'd like to use iceberg not from java (or python which apparently uses java).  The API documentation of the client claims it supports REST catalogs.  Is this the same as a nessie catalog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are different. There are many [Iceberg Catalogs](https://iceberg.apache.org/concepts/catalog/) you can use:

- REST
- Hive Metastore
- Hadoop
- Nessie
- JDBC

REST is used as an example in the Iceberg website and Nessie is contributed by the Dremio team as an open source project.

However, functionally they are the same...

Comment: "*However, functionally they are the same*" Can you clarify this? If they are all the same then why would there be five different ones? I think it's best if you just revert this edit to remove that claim, as they really are _not_ functionally the same beyond "they all allow you to manage table data".

Comment: There are different options for you to decide which one is more appropriate. If you, already have an RDBMS in place, you could decide to go with a JDBC. If you are currently using Hadoop or Hive, you could opt to use them. Nessie and REST are the recommended latest catalogs getting pushed by Dremio and Starburst respectively. In my case, I'm evaluating using the AWS Glue Catalog since my company is already using AWS to host our data. I looked into Nessie and it did not support having different "databases/namespaces" where tables were to be created.

Comment: To add context to the question/answer, Nessie is an open service catalog that does multiple things, such as enable data version control and enables cross table transactions. It happens to have a rest api on the service and is not adopted by the Iceberg community. The REST catalog is an Open API spec that declares a unifying api spec. There is additionally an implementation of this spec that can translate between most (maybe all) of the existing catalogs. https://github.com/apache/iceberg/blob/main/open-api/rest-catalog-open-api.yaml

Comment: Nessie currently only adds multiple table transactions, but this gap will be closed soon in the community and it’s recommended to just use the Apache Iceberg REST Catalog if you’re starting from scratch. Most need this for a smooth migration.

Comment: Thank you for all the info.  How can I **run** the REST catalog?  Is there "the Rest catalog" or is it only a spec?

Comment: You can run an implementation from Tabular as a docker container. You can check https://blog.min.io/a-developers-introduction-to-apache-iceberg-using-minio/ the source for the docker image is in this repo: https://github.com/tabular-io/iceberg-rest-image/

Comment: Nessie can facilitate multi-table transactions over multiple sessions, so instead of a "BEGIN/END Transaction" paradigm, you create a branch and transactions can occur on that branch across multiple sessions, multiple users, using multiple tools and all be merged at the same time. Nessie all enables catalog level tags which if you have a lot of tables makes things a little easier to replicate the state across many tables instead of tagging each individually. Essentially, Nessie big difference is it provides catalog level semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Project Gravitino provide RESTful service for Iceberg Catalog, here is detail: https://datastrato.ai/blog/gravitino-iceberg-rest-catalog-service.
About project gravitino, please refer: https://github.com/datastrato/gravitino